# How can I switch an existing 'Class Libray' project to target .NET 5

Tags: .net-5

I have multiple class library projects targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. I want to upgrade to .NET 5. In the project properties I only see versions of the .NET framework, I don't see .NET 5. I know I could open the project as a file and modify the target framework but what is the correct way of doing it with the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft provides [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/example-migration) a good migration example. You can also check [this post](https://www.outsystems.com/blog/posts/migrating-from-net-framework-to-net-core/) with another example.

If you intend to do this gradually, keeping common packages compatible with both `.NET Framework` and `.NET 5`, you may use [`.NET Standard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) projects/packages for that.